# Stripe handling the customer.subscription.deleted

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a code that disables the user to access  my website upon receiving this event : customer.subscription.deleted . However, I want to set a specific condition before applying this code.
I have two cases, in one case, if the user is subscribed to  INFINITE plan, he pays 40$ each month for 5 months (cancel_at field of subscription  is set after 5 months)and then when the subscription ends, his access to the website remains valid. so after 5 payments, he no longer pays, but he still have access to the website. whereas in a second case, if the website's admin manually cancels the subscription or if it is cancelled after many failed payments, I want to disable the user's access. so is there any condition I can set to differentiate between a subscription that was cancelled after being fully paid and another one  that was cancelled before it is fully paid ?

Comment: Can you store dates in a database and keep track of it that way?

Comment: thank you for answering.. I prefer not to rely on my database .. but a good idea based on your  suggestion would be to test if the current date (upon receiving the deleted event) is before the cancellation date of the subscription , if that's the case than the subscription is not payed fully.

Comment: That makes total sense but just relying on a database I don’t understand how you are storing that value.

Comment: In fact I am not storing it I can just retrieve it by calling the API :) the cancel_at field of a subscription can be retrieved from API.

Comment: Right I gotcha we do something similar but we have the privilege of a database. Don’t think I can help you from here though. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to keep track of this on your end, or using metadata on the Subscription that you kept up to date.  There's no way in Stripe to make this distinction.